# Check-in/check-out tool for Dropbox in Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, cloud, dropbox, shared-folders, version-control

Does anyone know whether there is a check-in/check-out tool for Dropbox running Ubuntu? I'm basically looking for the linux version of [Notifybox](http://www.notifybox.com), which only supports Windows.